# How to point R to the correct version of curl when upgrading from R 3.6 to R 4.0?

Tags: r, curl, https, libcurl

Note I have also posted this issue several months ago in RStudio Community with no resolution (https://community.rstudio.com/t/https-protocol-error-when-upgrading-from-r-3-6-to-r-4-0/88234/2).

Around 2018, I installed RStudio Server (free edition) with R 3.6.0 on a CentOS 7 server following the instructions found here: (https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-server/rstudio-server-pro-0.98.507-admin-guide.pdf )

Everything has been working with no issues. Recently, I've needed to upgrade the version of R, and have installed R 4.0.0 following the instructions here: (https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/ )

After installation, package installation on command line or in the RStudio IDE threw the following error:

```
Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I checked libcurlVersion() which returned:

```
[1] "7.47.0"
attr(,"ssl_version")
[1] "none"
attr(,"libssh_version")
[1] ""
attr(,"protocols")
[1] "dict" "file" "ftp" "gopher" "http" "imap" "pop3" "rtsp"
[9] "smtp" "telnet" "tftp"
```

So I can see https isn't listed in the protocols. There is another version of curl (7.73.0) on the computer (located in /usr/bin/curl) which does have https listed in its protocols, so I need to point R to this version instead. How can I point R to this version of curl?

Please let me know if there is additional information I can provide (wasn't exactly sure how to make a reprex for this one ;) )

Comment: This is an interesting problem. So you used `yum install` to install R? I guess this might be more of a general question of how `yum` determines which libraries to link against. You might get better support for a question like that at https://superuser.com/ since I'm not sure it's R specific.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will try superuser!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here was caused by installing R from precompiled libraries. To fix this I followed the instructions to install R from source (of course changing the URL in the curl step to the desired version of R):

https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r-source/

Before running the compile step under "Build and install R" I set PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib (which was the location of my libcurl 7.73.0) in the terminal, then followed the rest of the installation directions from there.

Finally, I edited the rserver.conf file to point to the new version of R, then restarted RStudio Sever and things are working fine.